# How do I find out the type of a Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference, lambda-calculus

Currently I am preparing for my exams and this is something about Haskell which I never really understood.

The type rule is the following

[image]

"und" means "and" in German.

So the given functions are

```
f :: ([a] -> b) -> a -> [b]
g :: c -> Int -> c
```

And now I have to determine the type `(f g)` by using the type rule above. Can someone explain me how to proceed at this point?

Comment: Please provide some context. A link to the document where you obtained the rule, etc. Right now it is unclear what gamma means.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm willing to bet gamma is a substitution, so that \gamma(\sigma) = \gamma(\rho) means that there is a way to unify the type of `t` with the input type of `s`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to quickly review, we know these facts:

1. If `s :: sigma -> tau`
   and `t :: rho`
   and `gamma(sigma) = gamma(rho)`
   then `s t :: gamma(tau)`.
2. `f :: ([a] -> b) -> a -> [b]`
3. `g :: c -> Int -> c`

We'd like to learn the type of `f g`. It looks like rule (1) could tell us that if we chose `s`, `t`, `sigma`, `tau`, `rho`, and `gamma` appropriately. Let's take a few guesses about how we could set them appropriately and see where that leads us.

- Since the conclusion of (1) says `s t :: ...` and we want to know `f g :: ...`, we should probably choose `s = f` and `t = g`.
- Since the premise of (1) says `s :: sigma -> tau` and we've chosen `s = f` and know `f :: ([a] -> b) -> a -> [b]` from (2), we should probably choose `sigma = [a] -> b` and `tau = a -> [b]`.
- Since the premise of (1) says `t :: rho` and we've chosen `t = g` and know `g :: c -> Int -> c` from (3), we should probably choose `rho = c -> Int -> c`.

Summarizing our choices, we have now transformed (1) to this form:

If `f :: ([a] -> b) -> a -> [b]`
and `g :: c -> Int -> c`
and `gamma([a] -> b) = gamma(c -> Int -> c)`
then `f g :: gamma(a -> [b])`.

There's only one variable from (1) that we haven't yet chosen a value for, namely, `gamma`. The third premise constrains `gamma` a little bit, namely, it must satisfy:

```
gamma([a] -> b) = gamma(c -> Int -> c)
```

Presumably there's an implicit assumption that it behaves like a substitution, that is, recursing over type structures and replacing type variables, so the previous equality assumption is equivalent to this one:

```
[gamma(a)] -> gamma(b) = gamma(c) -> Int -> gamma(c)
```

For this equation to be true, we must have all of these things:

```
gamma(c) = [gamma(a)]
gamma(b) = Int -> gamma(c) = Int -> [gamma(a)]
```

If we make an arbitrary choice for `gamma(a)`, these equations tell us the results of `gamma(b)` and `gamma(c)`; let's choose `gamma(a) = a`. Then:

```
gamma(a) = a
gamma(b) = Int -> [a]
gamma(c) = [a]
```

Now we have satisfied the premises of (1), and so we learn its conclusion:

```
f g :: gamma(a -> [b])
f g :: gamma(a) -> [gamma(b)]
f g :: a -> [Int -> [a]]
```